# Except doesn't catch error from C sprintf

Tags: python, error-handling, except

In python I have a function from a module which gives me an error:

```
ExecutiveRMS-Error: Atom counts between selection sets don't match (20 != 0).
```

I try to catch the error like this:

```py
try:
    # so this raises the error noted above
    pymol.cmd.pair_fit(*fit_args)
except:
    print("Error message not printed")
```

But this doesn't seem to work, probably because it is not an exception.

The error message is generated in C like this:

```c
sprintf(buffer, "Atom counts between selection sets don't match (%d != %d).",
          op1.nvv1, op2.nvv1);
ErrMessage(G, "ExecutiveRMS", buffer);
```

```c
int ErrMessage(MSKContext * G, const char *where, const char *what)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s-Error: %s\n", where, what);
  return (0);
}
```

**How can I catch the error message like you would do with `try` `except`?**

Comment: As far as I can tell, `ErrMessage` isn't part of the [C-API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html).  Is it a user defined function?  If so, we'll probably need to see that code to be any help...

Comment: The C needs to call something like `PyErr_SetString()` and then return `NULL` to raise an exception.

Comment: @cdarke but what if I don't want edit the C code, how could I catch this error as if it where an exception?

Comment: You could use IOString to catch the error message.